# error message "Min expected input to be a list but got the number 324 instead" when try to plot graph in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

really need advice on this, i want to plot graph where the x-axis is evacuation time (should start from 0 until max time required for people evacuate) and y-axis is N# turtles. below is code, when all peoples leave the room, graph will plot later, however when the simulation is done, it pop-up this error message "Min expected input to be a list but got the number 324 instead. 324 is max time-to-evacuate. anywhere in the code i did wrong?please advice. thanks

```
globals [
time-to-exits
time-to-evacuate]

to setup
set time-to-exits []
set time-to-exits lput time-to-evacuate time-to-exits
end

to go
if (flag-active-alarm )[active-alarm] 
if all? turtles [ pcolor = red ]   ;stops simuation
[plot-time-to-exits
stop ] 
end

to plot-time-to-exits
set-current-plot "Escape-Time"
set-plot-x-range min time-to-evacuate max time-to-evacuate
set-current-plot-pen "evacuated"
plot-pen-down
plot count turtles
end
```

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote:

```
min time-to-evacuate max time-to-evacuate
```

I think you must have meant:

```
min time-to-exits max time-to-exits
```

`time-to-exits` is a list of values, so it makes sense to use `min` or `max` with it. In contrast, `time-to-evacuate` is just a single number.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the command **min**, I got it to read the list by including the list primitive.

```
min (list time-to-evacuate)
```